# Comparing bigint values in pgsql

Tags: postgresql, casting

I have an issue in converting a character varying(20) to bigint and checking the range for example in the where clause I have:

```
where k.broj::bigint  >= 402099 and k.broj::bigint <= 4020991112649
```

this gives me an error

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""
********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: ""
SQL state: 22P02
```

Comment: The real question is: Why are you storing numbers in a `varchar` column? That's a pretty bad idea to begin with (and your current problem is just one symptom of that decision)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty string is not a valid number, you need to convert that to null, e.g.

```
where nullif(k.broj,'')::bigint >= 402099 
  and nullif(k.broj,'')::bigint <= 4020991112649
```